# Get the buttons number

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

This is my HTML code. I am using selenium.

```
<button class= "message-anywhere-button mn-connection-card__message-btn button-secondary-medium" aria-label="hello" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-62="62">
<span aria-hidden="true"> Msg</span>
<span class="visually-hidden"> hello</span>
```

I have a list of more buttons like this one, and I need to get the number of the "Msg" Buttons.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
message=drive.find_element_by_WHAT? (I tried id, class,css selector,but no one worked..)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same classname is present more than once.Try using `find_elements` and then count the length.

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".button-secondary-medium")))
```

Or try with area-lable if it is exists more than once.

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='hello']")))
```